# Removed Question vs Reputation

Tags: support, specific-question, reputation, deleted-questions

Recently, I lost $60$ points of my reputation because a question was removed. The question wasn't a Spam, it was a simple question of fractions but useful for the OP.
The question was

*Determine if $\frac{k−1}{k}+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k}{k+1}$ holds.*

I just want to know why this question has been removed.  It seemed to be arbitrary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such questions are usually deemed off-topic as they show no effort on your part.

Comment: The OP's part you mean.

Comment: Yes. I was going for a generic your.

Comment: [Found the question (10k users only)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079147/determine-if-frack-1k-frac1kk1-frackk1-holds).

Comment: Your question was not removed by moderators, it was removed by users with more than 10k reputation. It had been closed for almost a month as "off-topic (no context)", and wasn't improved. Deleting is generally the next step. Saying it was "arbitrary" is a bit unfair.

Comment: Ok. This question was not improved, but the answers was useful. Why delete the reputation points acquired? I think it is not so fair.

Comment: As suggested in some answers [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/under-what-circumstances-is-it-appropriate-to-delete-a-question-that-has-receive), one possible way to go would be improving the question, so that id does not get closed and deleted.

Comment: Question undeleted. You should get your points back.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson. Should I (or someone else) edit the question in order to avoid another deletion?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know what you can do to stop those bent on deletion. The usual objection to questions is that they show no effort, but this one shows a considerable amount of effort. But I wish you good luck.

Comment: How were three people able to delete a question with a +6 answer?

Comment: @Gerry and Alex: Hopefully you both noticed the effort was added after the question was deleted, by someone else than the OP, and this led to the question being undeleted and reopened...

Comment: @Isaac [The rules are laid out here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071) The number of deletion votes required to delete a question is $3 + \lfloor (\text{question score } + \text{ top answer score})/20 \rfloor$ (capped at $10$). Here $3 + \lfloor (0+6)/20 \rfloor = 3$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I noticed that.

Comment: @Alex Great. In general your answers to closed questions are always at risk of being deleted, so I think it's a good idea to try to improve the *questions* in this situation -- everybody is winning if you do it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: How is one to "improve" a perfectly clear question that shows no work, merely saying something to the effect "I don't know how to attack this"? Invent an approach that doesn't work? Add a complete solution to the OP and answer by saying yes,  that's good?

Comment: @AndréNicolas It's a good thing the question wasn't improved simply by adding "I don't know how to attack this", then.

Comment: Another conclusion one could reach is that if there's no way to improve a question so that it becomes suitable for the website, maybe it's a sign that the question should be deleted. This seems like common sense, but then again, who knows...

Comment: @GerryMyerson "...I don't know what you can do to stop those bent on deletion. ...this one shows a considerable amount of effort." Speaking as one who deletes often: Sure, I delete questions with good answers, but I also try to improve questions if I really like the answer. If someone is upset an  answer of theirs was deleted, they can edit the question--those who delete are also fairly quick to undelete.

Comment: (Also, the revision history shows that [Martin Sleziak contributed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19646658#19646658) the "considerable effort" to the question after this meta discussion was created.)

Comment: @Alex: I don't think further editing is necessary. Martin used a set of examples with small values of a parameter. That is certainly a reusable idea. André's point about this not being available to all contentious question (call this set $A$) is most likely valid. Then again not all question are salvageable (call this set $B$). I am trying to find what to do with $A\setminus B$. I am not claiming that the difference is an empty set. A bit of creativity may be needed?

Comment: The editing by @Martin was phrased in such a way as to make it seem as if it had been done by OP (in particular, the continued use of the 1st person). I'm not sure that I approve of editing in such a way as to leave that impression.

Comment: @GerryMyerson perhaps in the end it'd been better it stayed deleted, then. ;-)

Comment: @Gerry: It we do this all the time, we will leave a trail of somewhat fake questions in our wake. I'm not happy about that either. Do you see other alternatives to un/delete wars terminated by a moderator flipping a coin (or making a personal preference). Ideally I would like to educate the newbies about this, but this necessitates a site-wide near universal agreement not to answer such questions. The LHF pickers and the askers are blocking the road towards this ideal.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I have seen similar edits and I was under the impression that this is not an uncommon practice. As I do not want to duplicate content and this discussion moved a bit from the original question, I will post link to chat, where this issue was briefly discussed [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19658630#19658630) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19664923#19664923).

Comment: @Jyrki What do you mean by a "fake question"?

Comment: @Najib: "somewhat fake" = "where somebody else takes the role of the asker, and adds some partly contrived effort". Not ideal, but better than many alternatives.

Comment: @Jyrki If the end result is a clear question with context and answers that benefits both the OP and future readers, I'm not sure how that's not ideal... Will it be important in a year, or even a week, if the OP or someone else included context?

Comment: There are people downvote my answer for this question I think just for inciting its re-deletion. This is completely unfair, because the answer is correct. For those who don't accept the undeletion of this question and donwvoted my answer, I just ask if you think this is dignifying.

Comment: @Najib: That is also true.

Comment: @Alex: Thinking the downvotes are for inciting its re-deletion doesn't make much sense in light of how deletion works.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, Directly not. But, if the answers are not upvotes and considering the contentious about the question, the re-deletion is easier I think. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Martin, I'm happy that you edited the question to improve it, and I hope that you, and others, will continue to edit questions to improve them. My unease stems from your edit being so seamless as to appear to have been part of the original post. In particular, OP used "I", and you continued to use "I", so (unless we check the revision history) it looks like it was all written by OP. I would have felt better, had it been clearer what was OPs and what was yours.

Comment: @Jyrki, my modest proposal: no question from a new user gets put on hold until it has been up for 24 hours. Instead, constructive comments are left, indicating the faults in the question, and suggesting remedies. Once such a comment is posted, no one posts an answer to the question, until such time as the question has been improved. If someone does post an answer to the question before it has been improved, others leave comments explaining why this is A Bad Thing, and are free to vote the answer down mercilessly.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Everyone is already free to downvote answers mercilessly. They don't do it, at least not nearly enough to deter hasty answers.

Comment: @Gerry While I agree with your sentiment of giving new users more consideration, I strongly disagree with your proposed restriction on posting answers. At any time, everyone should feel free to contribute any content that they think will prove educational. I find it quite sad the way the site has evolved recently. We should be here to share our mathematical knowledge - not create complex mazes that prevent others from doing so. What a shame. I no longer recommend this site due to all this anti-pedagogical nonsense.

Comment: @user147263, it's a package. It only works if enough people agree to all parts of it. Anyway, the same people who now vote mercilessly to close questions from newbies can be counted upon to vote down answers.

Comment: @Bill, since you and the-user-that-keeps-changing-its-name both criticize my suggestion, I have some confidence that I'm on the right track. I don't see either side winning the war currently being waged, so I'm proposing a ceasefire. It's a compromise. Neither side gets everything it wants; both sides get something of what they want. If it works here, I will offer my services to the UN, to mediate the Arab-Israeli conflict.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I agree that your proposal is good at least in theory. Except I think answers should be deleted; they could *then* be undeleted.

Comment: @Gerry: I wish you stay in math, but it's nice to have back-up career plans. In theory your idea should help. Not unlike [The Question Triage](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19364/11619) being currently tested. The problem with anything like "gentlemen's agreement" is that not all users are gentlemen, and some would break the deal either by answering or voting to delete anyway. Putting the question on hold keeps the LHF-pickers at bay, but leaves the deleters uncontrolled. Not putting the question on hold has the opposite problem. We need to block all action other than comments+edits.

Comment: @Jyrki, if my proposal, or some variant of it, appeals to the moderators, then I imagine they have tools at their disposal for dealing with those who break the agreement. I hope it wouldn't come to that, but it might need at the least a few sharp words from the moderating team, and it might need a bit more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about. In general, if a question is badly written, has no context or shows no effort then **you** are taking a risk by answering it. If you are willing to take the risk (of losing reputation) then go ahead and answer it if you must however it is important to keep in mind the communities attitude to such questions.

They will most likely be closed. It is best not to write a really good answer to a terribly written question but to write a really god answer to an at least decently written question.

Don't take these kinds of things personally, the OP of the question is the one the action is being taken against.

Comment: Thanks Alizter. This is the answer that I need. I will keep that in mind. :)

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph alone. There are 100k+ members who take this way too personally. Even in the cases when they won't lose any points (I know that they are more interested in "valuable content" than points - you be the judge). The rule is that if the question survived for at least 2 months, then the answerers get to keep the points. @Alex was more than a bit unlucky this time.

Comment: What is presented here as "the communities attitude to such questions" is, in fact, the attitude of a part, and only a part, of the community. There are other parts of the community taking very different attitudes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If such questions are having action taken against them then does that not mean a *majority* of the community feels this way? So it is not just a part.

Comment: @Alizter: Not exactly, a small number of people can go on a rampage.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In which case action can be taken on the meta and the community can be made aware of the issue and it can be resolved.

Comment: This has been discussed ad infinitum, Alizter, you can go through the history here on meta if you wish. Suffice it to say that the community is well aware of the issue (well, those who have been following the discussions on meta are well aware of the issue), and resolution is awaiting the coming of the Messiah.

Comment: @Gerry Only a part of the community is aware of this issue, evidently. You cannot complain in one comment that someone used "community" to mean "a majority of the community" and then do the same thing in the next.

Comment: @Najib, I thought I pre-empted your objection with my parenthetical clause limiting the scope of my comment to "those who have been following the discussions on meta".

Comment: @Gerry So your statement is "the people who have been following this issue are aware of this issue". I didn't think you would post something that bland, hence my comment.

Answer (score 4):

I was delighted to see that [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079147/determine-if-frack-1k-frac1kk1-frackk1-holds) causing this discussion was improved (=edited significantly so that it now meets our quality criteria). In response to that the question was then duly undeleted by users with this privilege (in this case Fundamental, MJD and Gerry Myerson), and later reopened! Alex Silva (as well as other answerers) should have their lost points restored.

The message I want to repeat is: *Improving the questions is the best way to protect them from deletion.* Any user with +2k rep points has the privilege to edit posts. Those with less need to get their edits approved. Use this privilege to protect content that you want to keep.

Comment: I apologize to the named users for violating their privacy in this way. As these users are not always seen on the same side of un/delete skirmishes, I felt the need to bring this up as evidence showing that we **can** co-operate in this. If you want your name removed, ping me or flag this answer.

Comment: I don't think there's any privacy violated, the names are publicly displayed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1079147/revisions) (even an unregistered user can see this page as long as the question stays undeleted). You might want to note that the question has also been reopened.